Azure Bot: Failed to acquire token for client credentials
I have hosted Azure Bot and AppService connected to it. With MicrosoftType = MultiTenant, everything worked fine. After that I decided to add MicrosoftType = UserAssignedMSI with Managed Identity. Unfortunately locally it's cannot be debugged properly. I received an error shown below.
Error image
The full error description is here:
Failed to acquire token for client credentials. ([Managed Identity] Error Message: No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId. Managed Identity Correlation ID: 556f59d3-fb98-4c59-a358-0b6eeddd0db4 Use this Correlation ID for further investigation.) [Managed Identity] Error Message: No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId. Managed Identity Correlation ID: 556f59d3-fb98-4c59-a358-0b6eeddd0db4 Use this Correlation ID for further investigation.
I went through Bot builder authentication
The description here is well-defined. So using samples I wanted to sign in or at least to see the dialog window for authentication.
I expected to test the results using Azure Bot | Test in Web Chat

My guesses its something related to /msi/token. I havent implemented it, unless it was implemented in scope of the ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication that I am using for authentication purposes

And I didnt add any role assignments to my managed identity, as I assumed it will behave as a regular user

https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/TestConnectionCallback works fine as well in Azure Bot

You cannot switch an Azure Bot from one type to another. If you create a new Azure Bot resource of type Managed Identity, then you can use your existing bot code and app service with that new Azure Bot. Please confirm whether you created a new resource or not.
If you want to migrate your existing bot code/App Service to Managed identity (after creating new Azure bot resource), you will need to do the following:

Ensure the Managed Identity has been added to the App Services via the Identity blade.
Configure the following settings in the application: MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppTenantId and MicrosoftAppType (value: UserAssignedMSI). Where the Client ID value of the Managed Identity is used for MicrosoftAppId.
Do not have MicrosoftAppPassword configured.


I created new Azure Bot, the value is UserAssignedMSI. Everything as you have mentioned is created. But the error still preserves.

You did add the Managed Identity to the App Service's Identity\User Managed section?

Yes all of the above was implemented, but as I described below, I reconsidered how Bot should work and under what requirements, and applied the changes/

On Microsoft docs I have found one interesting Note (original link):

Note: The token issued during Bot authentication isn't the same token
issued during User authentication. The first is used to establish
secure communication between a bot, channels and, ultimately, client
applications. The second is used to authorize the bot to access
secured resource on behalf of the user.

Therefore after that comment I decided to

register app as Multitenant (in App registry in Entra ID),
remove managed identities
recreate Azure Bot as multitenant but to add OAuth Connection Strings

And in result I could contact my bot with my token.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
